# I think this is a bug in emacs indent mode

Tags: emacs, indentation

I happened to be writing something like this:

```
int main( int nargs, char **args ) {
    int i, j;
    if ( i > 0 && NEAR( i-1, j ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i-1, j ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i-1, j ).X = i;
        NEAR( i-1, j ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i-1, j ));
    }
    if ( j > 0 && NEAR( i, j-1 ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).X = i;
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i, j-1 ));
    }
    if ( i < maxwid && NEAR( i+1, j ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i+1, j ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i+1, j ).X = i;
        NEAR( i+1, j ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i+1, j ));
    }
    if ( j < maxheight && NEAR( i, j+1 ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i, j+1 ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i, j+1 ).X = i;
        NEAR( i, j+1 ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i, j+1 ));
    }
}
```

When I wrote it, emacs (22.2.1 of 2010-03-30, Ubuntu) indented it very badly:

```
int main( int nargs, char **args ) {
    int i, j;
    if ( i > 0 && NEAR( i-1, j ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i-1, j ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i-1, j ).X = i;
        NEAR( i-1, j ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i-1, j ));
    }
    if ( j > 0 && NEAR( i, j-1 ).dist == INFINITY )
    {
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).dist = 1.0;
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).X = i;
        NEAR( i, j-1 ).Y = j;
        newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i, j-1 ));
    }
    if ( i < maxwid && NEAR( i+1, j ).dist == INFINITY )
        {
            NEAR( i+1, j ).dist = 1.0;
            NEAR( i+1, j ).X = i;
            NEAR( i+1, j ).Y = j;
            newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i+1, j ));
        }
        if ( j < maxheight && NEAR( i, j+1 ).dist == INFINITY )
            {
                NEAR( i, j+1 ).dist = 1.0;
                NEAR( i, j+1 ).X = i;
                NEAR( i, j+1 ).Y = j;
                newWorkPoints.push_back( IPoint( i, j+1 ));
            }
            }
```

It's the occurence of the < in the expression that's doing it.  This seems like an unlikely bug!  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's correctly guessed your language mode? I agree that does seem to be an odd result.

Comment: FWIW my installation of GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.7.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) indented your code very nicely.

Comment: Emacs 23.2.1 indented the code correctly.

Comment: Indented nicely here too, GNU Emacs 22.1.1 in c-mode.

Comment: Try starting emacs with -q to not load your init file. try inventing and if that's satisfactory, then its something in your config causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to tell if you're doing something wrong as you didn't really give enough information.  What version of emacs are you using?  What version of cc-mode are you using?  Is the buffer even in java/c++/c-mode?

The cc-mode manual has good documentation on [customizing indentation](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Customizing-Indentation.html#Customizing-Indentation), and often the first place to start is with [interactive customization](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Interactive-Customization.html#Interactive-Customization).

Comment: I did give the version: (22.2.1 of 2010-03-30, Ubuntu).

Comment: I thought I'd try 22.3, as suggested above, and that fixed the problem. To be complete, I decided to reload 22.2 and show that the problem came back...but it didn't!!!  So the problem is not reproducible, at least not by me.  I didn't touch my init files or run with -q.  So I guess we're done here; thanks everyone for your good thoughts that clearly have solved my problem.